# Setting streaming-kafka-integration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

After reading the documentation on this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/streaming-kafka-integration.html for integrating spark-streaming with Kafka and Python it is not obvious for me how to set it. One of the things i cannot find out is what argument must be passed for the [consumer group id] parameter of the createStream method. So how the parameters must be set for obtaining a receiver ? I want stream a simple text from the topic and receive it in python. For example when i do it from the terminal i use this cmd "kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic data --from-beginning". I want to achieve the same thing using Receiver-based Approach in pyspark. After executing my code i an error.

```py
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = master \
+ ' ' + casandraPacks \
+ ' ' + startStream \
+ ' ' + jars \
+ ' ' + py_files \
+ ' ' + 'pyspark-shell'


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("app") \
    .getOrCreate()

def getData(spark):
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
    scc = StreamingContext(spark, 3)
    topic = "data"
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(scc, "localhost:2181", "", {topic: 4})
    lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
    print(lines)
    #rdd = kafkaStream.flatMap(lambda line: line.strip().split("\n")).map(lambda strelem: float(strelem))
    # print("****** ", rdd.count())
    scc.start()
    scc.awaitTermination()


getData(spark)
```

```py
line 77, in createStream
jlevel = ssc._sc._getJavaStorageLevel(storageLevel)
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute '_getJavaStorageLevel'
```

Comment: Since you've just started with stream processing in Spark please use [Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) instead since that's the stream processing engine of Spark 2+. Thanks. I'd also delete the question right after you've switched to the alternative.

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski Thank you